# Is it possible to install template only from quickstart package?

Tags: joomla-3.x, templates, extensions, installation

Here is the thing, I have joomla website with lots of content. Then I found this great template. The thing is, I only have it's quickstart package.

So, how do I install it's template only? And it's extensions.

Sure, with the quickstart package it comes with all of its extensions. So I just need it's template and extensions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Extract the quickstart archive file on your local machine and find the XML file for the template which should contain a list of the files and folders necessary to install the template on it's own.

Copy these files and folders to a separate folder and create a ZIP archive (including the XML file).

You should now be able to install this on your Joomla website using the standard installer.

The extension files can similarly be separated into individual installation files.

As @Lodder says, it's probably best to run a backup on your production website as a precaution before trying to install the template or other extensions or maybe try installing on a test copy of Joomla first.

Comment: Just finished compressing the template file only (all of it's needed files and folders) and it's system plugin (it's framework) and done. I upload it via extensions manager. Great clue pal! It works, at least for now, hope it don't screw up then. And that works on the extensions too. Just find which modules I want to use, then compress each module. 1 ZIP archieve for template, 1 for system plugin (template's framework), 1 for a modul. Make separated zip file for each module. I guess you can edit your answer, just a summary for my comment for the more detailed answer. Cheers...

Answer (score 2):

Yes it possible .  you just need to unzip the quickstart and locate all the files for the template in the templates folder. also read the xml file for the themplate to find all the files for it. 
You can upload then the templates files to your site with ftp client like filezilla and use joomla extension discover install to install the template to the site.

Answer (score 1):

I'd say there are a couple of approaches for this, but I'll just show you the easiest.

Before anything, the most important step is, take a backup of your site, either manually or using Akeeba Backup.

---

Now, in the quickstart zip file, it should show the entire Joomla site.

From this zip file, extract the following directories on to your computer:

- administrator
- components
- modules
- libraries
- plugins
- templates
- media
- images

Once done, zip all these directories up, and upload the zip file to the root of you online Joomla site. The extract it.

---

Login to the Joomla administrator and go to:

> **Extensions** (*top menu*) >> **Manage** >> **Discover**

It should show you a list of all the extensions from the quickstart package (including the template) and allow you to install them.

Hope this helps

Comment: I'll try later and report it soon. But sorry, can I achieve it with some way without accessing my hosting's cPanel? I mean like can I just upload it from the backend?

Comment: @adadion - No. A quickstart package must be uploaded to the server via FTP anyway.